# Excel formula: finding total Max sum, instead of individually max

Tags: excel, indexing, max, match, offset

I have the following coding:

```
=INDEX(A:A;MATCH(MAX(IF(B:B="a";(OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1));));OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1);0))
&INDEX(A:A;MATCH(MAX(IF(B:B="b";(OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1));));OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1);0))
&INDEX(A:A;MATCH(MAX(IF(B:B="c";(OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1));));OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1);0))
&INDEX(A:A;MATCH(MAX(IF(B:B="d";(OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1));));OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1);0))
&INDEX(A:A;MATCH(MAX(IF(B:B="e";(OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1));));OFFSET(A:A;;MATCH(E31;1:1;0)-1);0))
```

This finds the Max value for five different types (a,b,c,d,e). Instead i want it to find the Maximum value of the five combined instead of each one of them. I know the result will be the same, but i need to add other criteria later, which can lead to a change if not summed up total.

[image: Link to picture for visual]

See cell F31 for result of the formula.

Comment: So in your example you get "BBBGGGIIINNNTTT" as the result of that formula. Are you saying you want to get just "TTT" beacuse that corresponds with the highest value of all of those?

Comment: No actually i want to get BBBGGGKKKNNNTTT. If you look at the picture row 10 & 12, i want to add a minimum value to column V of 25%, which means it should choose KKK instead of III (has the same value in column Z)

Comment: please define "combined", it is not clear at all what do you need

Comment: Right now it findt the max value of type a = 10%, type b = 11.2%, type c = 12%, type d = 13,2%, and type e = 14% separetly. I want it to find the max value by combining a,b,c,d,e = 60,4%.

Why do i want that?

Imagine if cell C12 had the value of 11% instead of 12%, then this would not be the optimal solution. However i want to add a minimum value for column F = 25%. Thereby it should select "KKK" even though "III" has 1% more in column C.